# Where to call instance of DynamoDB? Once or once for every request?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, concurrency, amazon-dynamodb

I am having trouble where to create my dynamodb instance for my application where multiple users interact with the app. Should I create it when the program loads and have client, or should I put it into my route which makes the call to the database, so every request to the login route will create an instance?

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({
    region: "us-west-2",
    endpoint: "http://localhost:8000"
});

//Is this the right place. Outside of where the database call is being made
var dynamodbDoc = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();


app.post('/login', function (req, res) {

//OR should I create a new instance of AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient() here every time a request is made?
//  var dynamodbDoc = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient(); ????

    var login_username = req.body.login_username;
    var login_password = req.body.login_password;

    var params = {
        TableName : "Users",
        Key: {
            'username': login_username,
            'password': login_password

        }
    };


    dynamodbDoc.get(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        else console.log(data);
    });

});


var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
    var host = server.address().address;
    var port = server.address().port;

    console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

From the docs it looks like requests will be made using nodes default http connection pool (assumed, not 100%).

The amazon sdk allows you to configure it with your own agent, specifying this size of your pool.

https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_new_agent_options

Which should be an upper bound on the number of connections that can be made to amazon sdk.  The following code was pieced together from node http and amazon node sdk docs, and is not tested, and might not be completely accurate:

```
var http = require('http');

var dynamoAgent = new http.Agent({maxSockets: 20})

AWS.config.update({
    region: "us-west-2",
    endpoint: "http://localhost:8000",
    httpOptions: {
       agent: dynamoAgent
    }
});
```

This should allow you to have a pool of 20 sockets.  I am not sure of the nuances of the maxSockets, (do requests block if a socket is available, how are sockets reused? How does keep alive work? etc).

20 is arbitrary and your apps number will probably require fiddling with to see what works best.

Node global agent defaults to infinite number of max sockets, which will probably be too many if you have very high traffic on your post endpoint.  It's probably more sane to limit the number of connections.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So can I pass this instance into other nodejs module too? For example I have a module called messages where I can create and delete messages from dynamodb. So is it good practise to pass this into the messages module (e.g var messageModule = createMessage(dynamodb doc); )?